# JSON data concatenate two data

Tags: javascript, json

In Javascript, How can I convert this JSON Data?

I need to concatenate the firstname and lastname into its fullname

**Data**

```
[
  {
    "lastname": "Stark",
    "firstname": "Tony",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Parker",
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Rogers",
    "firstname": "Steve",
    "id": 3
  },
]
```

This should be the result:

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "fullname": "Tony Stark",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "fullname": "Peter Parker",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "fullname": "Steve Rogers",
    "id": 1
  },
]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to concatenate two string fields into one in a JavaScript array?](/q/34576386/4642212). Related: [Concatenate each object property values of javascript array , properties are list of strings in javascript](/q/71812690/4642212), [How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?](/q/69056356/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse your data into JavaScript object and then with **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** function iterate over the items and populate your custom objects.

```js
const dataAsJson = `[
  {
    "lastname": "Stark",
    "firstname": "Tony",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Parker",
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Rogers",
    "firstname": "Steve",
    "id": 3
  }
]`;

const data = JSON.parse(dataAsJson);

const changedData = data.map(item => ({ fullname: `${item.firstname} ${item.lastname}`, id: item.id }));

console.log(changedData);
```

Comment: Weird, it returns data.map is not a function

Comment: oh, thanks. So I need to convert changedData into JSON by JSON.stringify() again?

Comment: Do you have an ES5 syntax for your answer? I need to support IE11 and I'm not using any transpiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153586/discussion-between-kay-singian-and-suren-srapyan).

Answer (score 0):

If this data is available to your script as a JSON string, then you can use `JSON.parse()` to obtain the array of objects.

Then do whatever you want with that array of objects.

Then, eventually, convert the resulting data back to a string using `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array#reduce`.

```js
const data = `[{"lastname": "Stark","firstname": "Tony","id": 1},{"lastname": "Parker","firstname": "Peter","id": 2},{"lastname": "Rogers","firstname": "Steve","id": 3}]`;

var result = JSON.parse(data).reduce((arr, obj) => {
  return arr.push({fullName : obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname, id: obj.id }), arr;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the string to get the data in JSON by using

> JSON.parse()

. If you're using es6, use this:

```js
const newArray = JSON.parse(yourArray).map((user) => ({
 fullName: `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`,
 id: user.id
}));
```

otherwise use this:

```js
const newArray = yourArray.map(function (user) {
 return {
  fullName: user.firstname + user.lastname,
  id: user.id
 };
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logically all you need to do is loop through the array and make a new object with the `firstname` and `lastname` contacted. So here is a non-fancy ES5 way to do this:

```js
// JSON Data parsed into JS Object
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"lastname":"Stark","firstname":"Tony","id":1},{"lastname":"Parker","firstname":"Peter","id":2},{"lastname":"Rogers","firstname":"Steve","id":3}]');

var newArr = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  newArr.push({"fullname": arr[i]["firstname"] + " " + arr[i]["lastname"], "id": arr[i]["id"]});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr)); // Convert to text for JSON.
```